# Convert single line data into multiline

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Consider this long input within the same line

```
ITEM1 12-Oct-2017 DAVID BRYCE 12-Oct-2017 Sold 400,000 0.410 1.37 0.97 2.34 ITEM2 12-Oct-2017 MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES 09-Oct-2017 Shipped 4,350,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19 ITEM2 12-Oct-2017 DAVID BRYCE 09-Oct-2017 Shipped 2,900,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19 ITEM1 12-Oct-2017 MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES 09-Oct-2017 Sold 2,200,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19
```

How can I do it in bash so that I can format into CSV format so that I can further process in spreadsheets?

Sample desired output :

```
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34 
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Are the name fields aways between two ISO dates?

Comment: I have tried to write a loop to look for the change in format and it is not elegant. Hence trying to see whether any other more elegant approach since my knowledge of sed or awk is very limited.

Answer (score 2):

Extended GNU **sed** approach (for your current input):

```
sed -E 's/ +(ITEM[0-9]+)/\n\1/g; s/ ([0-9])/|\1/g; s/([0-9]) /\1|/g;' file
```

The output:

```
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

**----------**

**Bonus** solution for additional condition: *"What if the first field is an arbitary one word? For example, **FILE,STAPLER,PEN,NOTEBOOK**?"*

Sample `file` content:

```
FILE 12-Oct-2017 DAVID BRYCE 12-Oct-2017 Sold 400,000 0.410 1.37 0.97 2.34 STAPLER 12-Oct-2017 MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES 09-Oct-2017 Shipped 4,350,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19 PEN 12-Oct-2017 DAVID BRYCE 09-Oct-2017 Shipped 2,900,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19 NOTEBOOK 12-Oct-2017 MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES 09-Oct-2017 Sold 2,200,000 0.045 11.31 4.88 16.19
```

---

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+) +([A-Z]+)/\1\n\2/g; s/ ([0-9])/|\1/g; s/([0-9]) /\1|/g;' file
```

The output:

```
FILE|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34
STAPLER|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
PEN|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
NOTEBOOK|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

Comment: Nice. What is the first field is an arbitary one word? For example, FILE,STAPLER,PEN,NOTEBOOK ?

Comment: @dctw, you have my bonus solution

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
sed 's/ITEM/\nITEM/g' input.txt | sed '/^$/d' | awk '{ print $1"|"$2"|"$3" "$4"|"$5"|"$6"|"$7"|"$8"|"$9"|"$10}'
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

**awk** one-liner.

If you have GNU-Awk then you can use this as it support multiline RS

```
$ awk -v RS="ITEM" 'FNR>1{a=""; printf RS$1"|"$2"|"; for(i=3; i<=NF-10+2; i++){a=a$i" "}; printf a$i; while(i++<NF) printf "|"$i; printf "\n"}' file

ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

We're using `ITEM` as record separator here.

**Solution-2** :

```
$ awk -v RS="ITEM" 'FNR>1{printf RS$1"|"$2"|"$3; for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) {k=(NF>10 && i<=NF-7) ? " "  : "|"; printf k$i} printf "\n"}' file 

ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed/awk`

```
$ sed 's/ ITEM/\nITEM/g' file | 
  awk -v OFS="|" 'NF>10{for(i=4;i<=3+NF-10;i++) {$3=$3 FS $i; $i=$(i+(NF-10))}}1'

ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|12-Oct-2017|12-Oct-2017|Sold|400,000|0.410|1.37|0.97|2.34
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|4,350,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM2|12-Oct-2017|DAVID BRYCE|09-Oct-2017|09-Oct-2017|Shipped|2,900,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
ITEM1|12-Oct-2017|MICHAEL LEE BRIDGES|09-Oct-2017|Sold|09-Oct-2017|Sold|2,200,000|0.045|11.31|4.88|16.19
```

Comment: GNU sed only with the `\n`